# Python NDB: what's the best way to have a Set instead of a List in property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, app-engine-ndb

in NDB you have repeated properties, they behave just like a native python list but i want them to behave just like native sets.
i need to have a set of keys that is without duplicates.
in python you can remove duplicates like `the_list = list(set(the_list))`,

but how would you implement this so it is automatic and i don't to think about this ?

Answer (score 2):

Three ways come to mind:

1. enforce the list (repeated property) is unique with a "setter" method that only inserts unique values;
2. likewise, enforce the list is unique with a [_pre_put_hook()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__pre_put_hook) method;
3. use the [key on each entity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#entity_keys) as your list, ndb will make sure they are unique.

Comment: could you explain some more about method 3 ? and how would you implement a setter (ndb validator only validates individual keys instead of the whole list of keys)?

Comment: For number 3, I was thinking that you could try and insert an entity with the key as the unique value.  If it fails, the value is not unique.

Comment: I don't understand. are you saying that NDB automatically makes `KeyProperty(repeated=True)` unique , like a set ? because it doesn't from my testing.

Comment: No, an entire model class would be the set, and entities would be the list members.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to subclass ndb.Property. Quite a few examples here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/subclassprop

Comment: I don't see an example that fits my bill, can I override a setter on the property? how would you implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct strategy would to build a custom SetProperty which subclasses the ListProperty, to enforce your requirements.

Have a read of up on Subclassing properties. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/subclassprop

This I believe is the correct way for implementing this type of property, rather than _pre_put hooks. That is generally too late to perform appropriate validation and feedback.

You could write custom setters, however you setter can't be the name of the property, so this will look odd.

The other alternative would be to use a validator which is allowed to coerce the value.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options